# i want find a given pattern in a paragraph in java Strings?

Tags: java, string, find

Here is my problem description,

```
String str="We may use the name you provide for your Google Profile across all of the services we offer that require a Google Account. In addition, we may replace past names associated with your Google Account so that you are represented consistently across all our services. If other users already have your email, or other information";
```

Now,

```
String pat="we offer";
```

so i need to find the pattern 'pat' in the string 'str' and also i need the words starts with same pattern ...like " we may","with your",...etc.

Comment: Help you with what? With a ready code?

Comment: try using String.split() method.. and  post what you have tried when posting the questions

Answer (score 1):

First you may split the para from the string pat. Then compare the words near 'pat'and find the pattern you need.

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a="We may use the name you provide for your Google Profile across all of the services we offer that require a Google Account. In addition, we may replace past names associated with your Google Account so that you are represented consistently across all our services. If other users already have your email, or other information";
        String b="we offer";
    String[] s= a.split(b);
    System.out.print("==============="+s[0]);
    System.out.print("==============="+s[1]);
        }
}
```

This is just an idea not a proper code. Please do the validation and exception handling.